# Priority queue with Max-Heap

Tags: java, beginner, algorithm, priority-queue

I'm studying with book "Introduction to Algorithms" and implemented PriorityQueue without existed Class.

I made a MaxHeap class with Array and made a PriorityQueue with my Heap class.

Actually code is working and refactored code I did my best,

but I'm beginner so I need feedback for anybody.

would you give me a opinion?

```
public class PriorityQueue {

    private Heap heap;

    public PriorityQueue(int[] src){
        heap = new Heap(src);
    }

    public int size() {
        return heap.size();
    }

    public int extractMax() throws Exception {
        if(heap.size() < 1)
            throw new Exception("heap underflow");

        int max = heap.get(0);
        heap.set(0,heap.get(getLastIndex()));
        heap.decrementSize();
        MaxHeapify(0);
        return max;
    }

    public int getMaximum() throws Exception {
        return heap.get(0);
    }

    private int getLastIndex(){
        return heap.size()-1;
    }

    public void increaseKey(int idx, int key) throws Exception {
        if(idx >= heap.size())
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        if(key < heap.get(idx))
            throw new Exception("new key is smaller than exist value");

        heap.set(idx,key);
        while(idx > 0 && heap.get(heap.getParentIndex(idx)) < heap.get(idx)){
            swap(idx, heap.getParentIndex(idx));
            idx = heap.getParentIndex(idx);
        }
    }

    public void add(int key) throws Exception {
        heap.checkCapacity();
        heap.incrementSize();
        increaseKey(heap.size()-1, key);
    }

    private void MaxHeapify(int idx) {

        if(idx < 0 || idx >= heap.size)
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        int leftIndex = heap.getLeftIndex(idx);
        int rightIndex = heap.getRightIndex(idx);
        int size = heap.size();
        int largest = -1;
        int tmp = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        // compare with leftNode
        if(leftIndex < size && heap.get(leftIndex) > heap.get(idx))
            largest = leftIndex;
        else
            largest = idx;
        // compare with rightNode
        if(rightIndex < size && heap.get(rightIndex) > heap.get(largest))
            largest = rightIndex;

        // swap if parentNode is bigger than child.
        if(largest != idx){
            swap(idx,largest);
            // recursive call
            MaxHeapify(largest);
        }
    }

    private void swap(int from, int to) {
        int tmp;
        tmp = heap.get(from);
        heap.set(from,heap.get(to));
        heap.set(to,tmp);
    }

    public String toString(){
         return Arrays.toString(heap.array);
    }

    public class Heap {
        int[] array = {};
        int size;

        public Heap(int[] src){
            array = src;
            size = array.length;
        }

        public Heap(){
            array = new int[10];
            size = array.length;
        }

        public int getLeftIndex(int idx){
            return 2*idx+1;
        }

        public int getRightIndex(int idx){
            return 2*idx+2;
        }

        public int getParentIndex(int idx){return idx/2;}

        // heap's size
        public int size(){
            return size;
        }

        // array's size
        public int length(){
            return array.length;
        }

        public void incrementSize(){ size++; }

        public void decrementSize(){
            size--;
        }

        public int get(int idx) {
            return array[idx];
        }

        // if heap's size is bigger than array's length, grow array's size;
        private void checkCapacity() {
            int oldCapacity = length();
            if(size >= oldCapacity){
                int newCapacity = oldCapacity + 10;
                array = Arrays.copyOf(array, newCapacity);
            }
        }

        public int[] getHeap(){
            return array;
        }

        public boolean isValid(int idx){
            return size-1 >= idx ? true : false;
        }

        public void set(int idx, int value) {
            if(isValid(idx)){
                array[idx] = value;
                return;
            }
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your coding style, that's good that I'm not the only one to use [Guard Clauses](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html), to clear the invalid states before entering the main code. Also, the methods are short and well named; I had no issues to find the code quickly, that's a big plus, in my opinion.

## Minor issues

#### Method `MaxHeapify`

- The name of the method should start with a lowercase.
- The variable `tmp` is unused.

#### Method `swap`

- The variable `tmp` can be on the same line as the initialization.

```java
   private void swap(int from, int to) {
      int tmp = heap.get(from);
      heap.set(from, heap.get(to));
      heap.set(to, tmp);
   }
```

#### Class `Heap`

- The initialization of the variable `array` with the value `{}` is useless, since the value is overridden in the constructor.

```java
    public class Heap {
      //[...]
      int[] array;
      int size;
      //[...]
   {
```

#### Method `Heap#isValid`

- The logic can be simplified.

```java
   public boolean isValid(int idx) {
      return size - 1 >= idx;
   }
```

Good job!

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, Doi9t!
I'm gonna refactor as yours.